# Boto3 and botocore python equivalent for credentials calls in typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js-v3

2

I have inherited a python lambda which I need to convert to node js. I am a bit stuck with the code that handles authentication and so I am wondering what the JS equivalent would be for the python code below:

```
import boto3
import json
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

region = "eu-west-1"
service = "es"

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

r = requests.get(url, auth=awsauth)
```

or this one

```
def get_credentials(session):
    session_credentials = session.get_credentials()
    if not session_credentials:
        return None

    read_only_credentials = session_credentials.get_frozen_credentials()
    expiration = None
    if hasattr(session_credentials, '_expiry_time') and session_credentials._expiry_time:
        if isinstance(session_credentials._expiry_time, datetime):
            expiration = session_credentials._expiry_time
        else:
            LOGGER.debug("Expiration in session credentials is of type {}, not datetime".format(type(expiration)))
    credentials = convert_creds(read_only_credentials, expiration)
    return credentials
```

Here is my work in progress at what seem to be relevant calls using the javascript aws-sdk:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk"

const region = "eu-west-1"
const service = "es"

const credentials = AWS.Credentials().get()

const response = await fetch(url, {
  headers: { Authorization: credentials },
  credentials: "include"
})
```

I know the python code works, so I just need to convert it to JS. As you can see I'm not really sure what to do with credentials once I have it or what the equivalent of auth=awsauth would be within the fetch call. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

below code

```js
import { Credentials } from "aws-sdk";

const credentials =  new Credentials();


console.log(credentials);
```

gives below output

```
Credentials2 {
  expired: false,
  expireTime: null,
  refreshCallbacks: [],
  accessKeyId: undefined,
  sessionToken: undefined
}
```

Comment: I use AWS SSO to login as part of control tower organisation so no access and secret keys